# Identify comic book about 1940's resistance fighters battling an alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, comics

Anyone know name of comic book from the 1940's about resistance fighter after devastating alien invasion. The fighters used a vehicle that was a large wheel. The driver would ride in the center and steer by leaning.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing that the comic you're looking for is [Blackhawk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhawk_%28DC_Comics%29). They often fought against something called the War Wheel.

[image]

Comment: @user14111 - Well sometimes memories get garbled up, so I thought a screen cap might jog the OP's memory either way.